# how to check if a discord member can change others role? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have two questions:

1. How i can check if member discord can do something? e.g change others role or move people?
2. How i can check/do something with member? bcs only way that i know is to:

   `async on_message()`

and then catch

```
     message.author
```

, but how i can do something with member without waiting for its message?
please dont send me a link do documentation bcs i have spent hours reading it and still dont know what to do...

Comment: One question at a time please. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

You can use this to check for permissions;
@has_permissions(administrator=False, manage_messages=True, manage_roles=True)
replace with the one you want

Comment: is this is a command? if yes can you send your code for the command?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the decorator `has_permission` on top of your method. Example:

```
from discord.ext import commands

# If the command issuer has the read message and manage role permission.
@commands.has_permission(read_messages=True, ban_members=True)
```

2. Think of whatever you might want to do, such as banning a member. Extending from the example above:

```
from discord.ext import commands

# If the command issuer has the read message and manage role permission.
@commands.has_permission(read_messages=True, ban_members=True)
@client.commands(name="ban")
async def ban_user(ctx, user: discord.User, reason: str = None):
    await ctx.guild.ban(user=user, reason=reason)
```

The example above is trivialized. You should consider adding various checks such as if the user is currently in the server, default the ban reason to something else if it's not specified, or sending the user an embed to let them know that they were banned (and perhaps the reason as well), or even extending it into a timed ban that automatically unban the user after a given duration.

There are a lot of simple bot examples out there available both on Google as well as in the form of YouTube videos. I would recommend you to look it up and try to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: okay fine, i think its working but only when member write a command, how i can catch member/some information without waiting for member write a command?

Comment: That is where the discord.py documentation kicks in. There are various ways to interact with a member's action, such as `on_message()`, `on_message_edit()`, `on_message_delete()`, `on_member_join()`, and so on. Please refer to https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html